# Sort the assets folder with Andengine

Tags: android, directory, andengine, assets, sorting

Google translator

I'm making a game with Andengine and inside the folder "assets" I have three folders gfx, mfx, font (protected folders are there more?)

The folders are full and it works fine.

On my game you can choose several players with different characteristics (speed, jump, aim) with time I will update when it is available on the market and I would like to have it all sorted. I can do this? If it is not possible that I seriously recomendais.

```
"assets/player/soldier001.png"
"assets/player/soldier001.xml"
```

Sorry for my English.
Google translator

Comment: are you talking about sorting the files in the folders? I'm not sure the order matters as long as they exist. If you are reading a list of the files in the folder then you probably should sort that yourself and not depend on the OS to keep it "in order"

Comment: No.. i want create a folder named "player" or other name, dont care, into "assets" with 2 type of file "*.png" and "*.xml". The PNG file is a sprite and XML its info for the sprite.

Comment: ok, you can do that - that shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

just right click on the assets folder - choose New - choose Folder and name it player. then drop your files in there.

Just be sure when you access those you use the correct filepath.

Comment: ok. now i will try.. the other time i tried only with creating the folder on the filexplorer of windows

Comment: that should work too. I always do it in Eclipse, but not sure what you are using either, so YMMV